# beamer: Sequence order- itemize and pictures

Tags: beamer, columns, pause

[image]

As shown in the picture, I want the following appearance order in beamer-latex:

```
slide1: item1+subitems,
slide2: picture1,
slide3: item2+subitems,
slide3: picture2
```

item1 and item2 are items of the highest itemize environment.

Any idea how I can do that?
Without difficulties I can place picture1 as a column next to the second itemize environment of item1, but I want to place it next to the item1 block.

This code does not work for me:

```
\begin{itemize}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\item a 
\begin{itemize}
\item a1
\item a2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\pause

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[...]
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\pause

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\item b 
\begin{itemize}
\item b1
\item b2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\pause

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[...]
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{itemize}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the minimal damage cure in this case is to start a new set of columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Pfffht}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\item a 
\begin{itemize}
\item a1
\item a2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\pause

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\pause
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\item b 
\begin{itemize}
\item b1
\item b2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\pause

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{itemize}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

NOTE: If you want to populate the columns in less structured way, you could use this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Pfffht}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item a 
\begin{itemize}
\item a1
\item a2
\end{itemize}
\only<3->{
\item b 
\begin{itemize}
\item b1
\item b2
\end{itemize}
}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\pause
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\pause\pause
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, in the present case the output will be much worse (which can of course be fixed), but something along the lines of this code will be useful if you have 3 items on the left and 2 pictures, say.

Comment: thank you very much! Could you please explain me, what the overlayarea - environment does? I have never heard it before :)

Comment: @opens It creates an area and prevents the stuff from jumping if you keep adding things to the slide. Notice that my answer is only good for the very situation you encounter. In the general case (some list on the left and some pictures on the right) you may want to work with `\only` in addition to the `\pause` commands.